# Outlook 2007 export contacts including list info

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, export, csv, contacts

I want to export all contacts in outlook 2007 for import to gmail. Many of the contacts are members of various distribution lists, but there are no info in the exported csv-file as to which distribution list they belong. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Import and Export" dialog doesn't do so, but the method described [here](http://worcester.edu/InformationTechnologies/GoogleGmail/Out072GM.pdf) looks like it should do the job well enough, if you don't mind it taking a reasonable amount of effort for each list you export.

Comment: Problem is not every contact is part of a list. Seems only way in this case is to then match exported lists against total contacts (800) which seems tedious.

Comment: Done some more research and it seems these distribution lists does not have any connection "backwards" at all to contacts. So you'll have to export contacts and the lists to csv and txt files. Then match them in xls.

Comment: Yup. Trust Outlook not to make anything simple.

Comment: Yeah, left Outlook 5 years ago. Coming back occasionally is like ..

Comment: Sure is. Me, I spent some time a few years ago learning how to VBScript and MAPI so that I could make Outlook less stupid, but since then I've switched everything over to Thunderbird and haven't looked back. Glad to be of help!